# Class class type in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, iphone, cocos2d-x, translate

The following syntax is from cocos2d

```
-(void) setLevelScene:(Class)klass
{
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[klass scene]]];
}
```

i want to change above cocos2d code to Cocos2dx,  as i know there is no type such as Class in COCOS2DX.

How can i change the code particularly Class class type or any alternative type in cocos2dx?

Can you assist me to change the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't have mechanism like isKindOf or class "that contain class name".
 If you want to check that object is an instance of a class you can use dynamic cast.

`dynamic_cast< Class* >(object)` <- this line will return null if object isn't an instance of Class

Another way is to use virtual method like ClassName();
 which you override in your every class and return a string with ClassName, for example:

```
 std::string MainLayer::ClassName(){
     return "MainLayer";
}
```

edit:

In your example I would write something like this

```
void setLevel(CCScene* scene){
 CCDirector::sharedDirector->replaceScene(CCTransitionFade::create(1.0f, scene);
}
```

and call like that

```
 setLevel(MainLayer::scene());
```

In this case you don't need any information about class in setLevel function. If you have many levels in your project good idea is use the Factory Method pattern.

Comment: Further i need to call the particular scene.   How can i create and call the "MainLayer"(in your example)?  (Like  MainLayer* obj;)

Answer (score 0):

```
void className:: setLevelScene(className* klass)
{
 CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(CCTransitionFade::create(1, klass));
}
```